# How to make a YouTube-like drop-down section in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In YouTube when you click the top right button of your profile it drops a whole section on the top, moving all the content down, when you click it again, the section disappears, moving all the content back up. How do they do that?

P.S. I'm new to Javascript, so I don't even know how to search docs for this particular solution. Please be specific in description.

Thanks!

Comment: First thing would be to learn about [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide) and [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM).

Comment: I know what Javascript is, I know what DOM is, your suggestion does NOT help my question at all. I'll appreciate actual answer. Thanks.

Comment: Well it is a comment, not an answer. You said you are new and that you cannot find information, so I assumed you still have to learn about it and provided links. Once you learned about it, you know how to manipulate the DOM in the way you want it. IMO your question is too  broad. Answers can range from "with DOM manipulation" to handing the code to you on a silver platter, which is not what we are doing here at SO. You have to show some effort to solve your problem yourself.

Comment: there is just a couple of examples http://www.harrymaugans.com/2007/03/06/how-to-create-an-animated-sliding-collapsible-div-with-javascript-and-css/ and http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/javascript-sliding-panels-using-generic-animation

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/qT3Em/

unless you want to write the animation yourself (not recomended)
you shuld use a libary witch comes with animations like jquery http://www.jquery.com

it commes with a function .toggle http://api.jquery.com/toggle/
that i used in the example belove

```
<button>A button</button>
<div style="display:none;">
 <h1>Hidden Content</h1>
</div>
<h1>Lower Content</h1>
```

---

```
$(function() {
 $("button").click(function() {
  $("div").toggle("slow");
 }); 
});
```

that will give you the effect you want